# How do you use dplyr to map a function that returns a list of normal distributions of different size

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a column using `dplyr` that will store the result of a function that returns a list of normal distributions with variable size. Something like this:

```
  var_a    new_col
  <dbl>    <list>
    1     <dbl [3]>         
    2     <dbl [9]>         
    3     <dbl [5]>         
    4     <dbl [8]>         
    5     <dbl [6]>
```

I found an example that does close to what I want but the distributions are size-fixed:

```
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

example_seq_tbl <- tibble(var_a = seq(from = 1, to = 5, by = 1))

# function that returns 10 values
x_function <- 
  function(x){
    rnorm(n = 10,
          mean = x
    )
  }         

# map function over var_a, now each observation in new_col has 10 values     
another_tbl <- example_seq_tbl %>%
  mutate(new_col = map(var_a, x_function)) 
another_tbl
```

which yields:

```
  var_a    new_col
  <dbl>    <list>
    1     <dbl [10]>            
    2     <dbl [10]>            
    3     <dbl [10]>            
    4     <dbl [10]>            
    5     <dbl [10]>
```

I successfully generated the dataframe but it is inefficient and ugly. It uses a `for` loop:

```
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

example_seq_tbl <- tibble(var_a = seq(from = 1, to = 5, by = 1))

# a function that requires size and mean. returns a list per distribution
xy_function <- 
  function(x, y){
    list(rnorm(n =  y,
          mean = x
    ))
  }

another_tbl <- example_seq_tbl
i <- 1
for (col in another_tbl$var_a) {
    another_tbl[i, "new_col"] <- map(col, xy_function, runif(n=1, min=2, max=10))
    i <-  i + 1
}
another_tbl
```

The main challenge with *dplyr*, `map` and  `xy_function` is that it will generate the distribution with the last size by `runif`; it will ignore recalculating a new distribution. Ideally this line:

`mutate(new_col = map(var_a, xy_function, runif(n=1, min=2, max=10)))`

should be returning normal distributions of different size as lists.

Is there a way to force `map` to recalculate `xy_function` for each row of the dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map2()` with 2 input vectors:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
example_seq_tbl <- tibble(var_a = seq(from = 1, to = 5, by = 1))
set.seed(123)

example_seq_tbl %>% 
  mutate(new_col = map2(sample(2:10, nrow(.), replace = TRUE),
                        var_a, 
                        rnorm))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   var_a new_col  
#>   <dbl> <list>   
#> 1     1 <dbl [4]>
#> 2     2 <dbl [4]>
#> 3     3 <dbl [3]>
#> 4     4 <dbl [7]>
#> 5     5 <dbl [6]>
```

Or switch to row-wise grouping:

```r
example_seq_tbl %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(new_col = rnorm(sample(2:10, 1), var_a) %>% list()) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   var_a new_col   
#>   <dbl> <list>    
#> 1     1 <dbl [3]> 
#> 2     2 <dbl [3]> 
#> 3     3 <dbl [10]>
#> 4     4 <dbl [5]> 
#> 5     5 <dbl [10]>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much. Both work! The only question I have is why `nrow(.)`? Which yields a constant `5`.

Comment: `sample()` in 1st example generates `n` arguments for `rnorm` and that vector length should match the length of `var_a`, i.e. the number of rows. It's evaluated exactly once. In 2nd example `sample()` gets called 5 times, once for every row.